# How does a multi platform git strategy looks like?

Tags: git, multiplatform

Let‘s assume you wanna build a project consisting of web apps, an iOS, iPadOS and watchOS and an Android App. All kinds of applications rely on the same database. For the backend APIs, REST gets used served by an express js instance with prisma handling ORM related tasks.

From various web projects in the past, I really enjoy the approach of having countless apps (Frontend and backend) and related libs within a single repository. Now I‘m wondering if that approach would also work across multiple platforms, as described above.

Is it a good idea to put every project into the same repository and work with different tags when merging into master? Are there other common practices to follow when developing multi-platform?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520497/strategies-for-multiplatform-project-repository-design or https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/5q7k3x/help_structuring_git_repo_for_multiplatform/

Answer (score 0):

In fact it's depend on your needs. It the same Paradigm for Multiplatform development (Windows, Linux, macOS, Xbox, PS5).
First, you have some questions to take in consideration to define how to work:

- 1 Do you plan to create a release on all platforms at the same time ?
- 2 Do you plan to update at least 1 time a year your application to follow platform target life-cycle ? For example each year you have at least one macOS or Windows big update.
- 3 What about techs or security updates management ?
- etc...

With **git**, You don't have a **Multiplatform Dev** approach.

Some developers use a specific repo for each platform others use a specific git branch for each platform...

My recommendation is to have only one repo and define multi-projects with all targeted platforms. For example, it include a Visual Studio project folder, an Xcode project folder...
The simple way to proceed is to develop with branches on your Dev Branch for each targeted platform like the addition of a new feature. Like this everything stay up to date and it's more easy to manage dependencies.

You can have a look on **Git Flow**.

https://zepel.io/blog/5-git-workflows-to-improve-development/